# iptables: No chain/target/match by that name while trying to accept SSH connctions

Tags: networking, iptables

I'm trying to use this rule to accept the SSH connections, however it doesn't work:

```
sudo iptables -A FORDWARD -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

And I got this error:

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

However, if I use this rule, it works:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

I checked if I have the iptables enabled in my system, and it is, so I don't think that happened because I don't have enabled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name is FORWARD, not FORDWARD.